# change the select box based on index

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have two select boxes.If I change the first select box it will change the value of 2nd select box.

```
   <p>First Name: 
  <select id="name-first">
    <option value="234">UK</option>
    <option value="15">US</option>
    <option value="12">France</option>
    <option value="927">U'K</option>
</select>
 </p>
   <p>Surname: 
   <select id="name-second">
    <option value="562">a</option>
    <option value="10">b</option>
    <option value="6">c</option>
    <option value="234">d</option>
    </select>
    </p>

  }  
   $(function(){

    $('#name-first').on('change',function(){
        $("#name-second option:contains('" + $("#name-first option:selected").index() + "')").prop('selected', true);
    });

});
```

if I choose 'uk' it will select 'a',If 'US' then 'b', etc.If I select the 1st select box 2nd select box get changed. this selection is based on index  or name or id.

Comment: Ehm, what's the question?

Comment: So what is the problem? what is not working?

Comment: none of these fields seem even remotely related... how on earth do you determine which checkbox to check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) and set it

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/muralim/9xqGL/)

```
$('#name-first').on('change',function(){
    var selIndex= $("#name-first option:selected").index();

    $("#name-second option").eq(selIndex).prop('selected', true);
});
```

For [**Vice-versa demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/muralim/9xqGL/1/)

Comment: I've a piece of code similar to yours (*somewhere in my PC*) where that, if you were to choose the other dropdown (Surname in this case), that the other dropdown would also switch accordingly. Giving the OP that extra feature, would be a bonus ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-, Thanks. I updated the vise-versa demo in my answer